# Text outside of span, offset from span outline

Tags: html, css, layout, fonts

I'm building a "We the People" website section inspired by the U.S. Constitution, and I'm listing names of "signers" supporting my project. The names have different sizes, and I'm trying to get them to show up nicely on the page. Strangely, the font is consistently offset from the spans containing the names. Here's what I have:

[image]

As you can see, the names overlap, which I'd like to avoid. What I find odd is that the text is outside of the span outlines:

[image]

The same is true of all the names. Here's my HTML:

```
   <div id="names">   
      <span class="order ten CalifornyaA-Bold" id="o3">Eric So</span> &nbsp;
      <span class="order twenty-five CalifornyaB-Bold" id="o5">Sierra Hansen</span> &nbsp;
      <span class="order ten CalifornyaB-Bold" id="o6">Eleanor Collier</span> &nbsp;
      ...
      <span class="order twenty-five CalifornyaC-Bold" id="o69">Maeve McCarty</span> &nbsp;
   </div>
```

... and CSS:

```
    #names {
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 10%;
    }
    .hancock, .five-hundred, .two-hundred, .one-hundred, .fifty, .twenty-five, .ten {
      line-height: 1.5em;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .hancock {
      font-size: 5.5em;
    }
    .five-hundred {
      font-size: 4em;
    }
    .two-hundred {
      font-size: 3.4em;
    }
    .one-hundred {
      font-size: 2.8em;
    }
    .fifty {
      font-size: 2.2em;
    }
    .twenty-five {
      font-size: 1.6em;
    }
    .ten {
      font-size: 1em;
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

its your `line-height` since they are inline elements an no block elements, try modifying the value:

```
.hancock, .five-hundred, .two-hundred, .one-hundred, .fifty, .twenty-five, .ten {
      line-height: 110%;//percent would be good
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

or add individual CSS rules for each one, instead of all being set to`1.5em`
**Edit:**
Remember to set a font-size to the parent element since you are using `em`, check how i wrapped a text and added a font-size in `em` in the page of the font and its not overlapping:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. 110% makes it look about the same; 200% prevents the overlap on the top, but it increases the spacing on the bottom too so that a large gap appears under the line with the largest name. And the text is still offset from the spans

Comment: Setting individual rules doesn't seem to work either, for the same reason: the text is still offset

Comment: i put `110` as an example, what is the name of your font?

Comment: It's a webfont suite called Californya: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typo5/californya/

Comment: i added an image, i tried searching for a free version (similar) font  to make an example but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
span {line-height: 1.2;}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work (same problem as with the answer below: text sill outside of span).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `display: inline-block` and then setting `margin-top` works fairly well. I think that's a bit of a hack solution, but it more or less works.